# Tier 4 Visa application

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, student-visa, uk-visa, study

I am planning on applying for a Tier 4 visa to do a Master's degree in medicine in the UK.

1. Will two previous UK visit visa refusals have a negative affect on my application?
2. My husband is a resident in the UK; he has his own flat and I'll be living there with him throughout my studies. Could this affect my chances of getting the student visa in any way?

I am indeed a genuine student and this research opportunity will have a tremendous impact on my professional portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

Your nationality and country of residence should not impact on your University application. It will however impact on your Master's degree fees. 
Once you are accepted for admission to university and you have received the confirmation of acceptance for studies (CAS), you can then apply for the Tier 4 visa. You can find all the most updated information you might need here: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/623341/T4_Migrant_Guidance_29_June_2017.pdf

If the university is a genuine Tier 4 visa sponsor, you are coming to study and you can demonstrate you have enough money to pay the visa fees, your visa should be pretty straightforward. The previous denials should not count against you if you demonstrate you are a genuine student. Be sure to fill out your forms accurately and correctly, leaving no ambiguity. Importantly, you need to demonstrate that you have enough funds to cover yourself, and your course fees for at least one year of study. Be transparent and do not be ambiguous when it comes to the part on the application when you must declare if you have been denied a UK visit visa previously.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You. Is it possible that you can help me with the second part of my question? Many thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure how that might affect things. When applying for the visa, you will have the opportunity to mention his involvement if he will help to support you. I do think it may raise the question for them and they will wonder if you are pursuing this academic activity in an effort because you were unable to obtain another visa to the UK. But as long as you have the study acceptance and are committed to it, I don't think it should matter.